# After update to DRF 3.0 and Django 1.8, Serialiser method invalid

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am not sure whether it is related or not. But before I update to DRF 3.0 and Django 1.8, my following code is working properly.

```
class DialogueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sound_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sound_url')

    class Meta:
        model = Dialogue
        fields = ('id','english','myanmar', 'sound_url') 

    def get_sound_url(self, dialogue):
        if not dialogue.sound:
            return None

        request = self.context.get('request')
        sound_url = dialogue.sound.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(sound_url)
```

Some people also said like this.
https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples/issues/2

Now, when I run, I got

> It is redundant to specify `get_sound_url` on SerializerMethodField
>   'sound_url' in serializer 'DialogueSerializer', because it is the same
>   as the default method name. Remove the `method_name` argument.

[image]

How shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your field is `sound_url` and your method `get_field_name` (`get_sound_url`), you don't have to give to `SerializerMethodField` the method name.

As you can see in the example from [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), there is no need to precise `method_name` in this case.

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

So, the result is :

```python
class DialogueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sound_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # no more `method_name` passed

    class Meta:
        model = Dialogue
        fields = ('id','english','myanmar', 'sound_url') 

    def get_sound_url(self, dialogue):
        if not dialogue.sound:
            return None

        request = self.context.get('request')
        sound_url = dialogue.sound.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(sound_url)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new here. If I don't have to give SerializerMethodField method name, how shall I modify my current code?